# How to find the current location of an element in browser?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, offset

I was wondering how we would be able to find the current location of the element in the browser. I am  trying to create a jQuery slider. Have created sliders by animating margins earlier. But this case is bit complicated. It has two navigations. one that will slide from one page to other. One page has four thumbnails. And using the bottom navigation you can slide through only one thumbnail. Please refer to the image below.

[image: slider]

I have been able to get this effect earlier by animating the margins. But it isn't very efficient and has a lot of bugs. So I thought I would rather do it from scratch again.

Now what I am planning to do is:

1. With the arrow navigation, animate the margin and go to next slide.
2. with the pagination, find out the current location of the thumbnail and animate margin equal to the width of article + gutter.

Is it possible to do it using jQuery offset? Please suggest me the right way. Any examples of sample code will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT:

I have actually finished the slider. It is working perfectly as I wanted. I will answer to this question in few days. Also when the site is completed I will share the link so others can see it in action. :)

Comment: There are **lots** of jQuery plugins already in existence that do this sort of thing. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thumbnails wont enlarge. it will just animate a bit, which I will do using css. when you press view then a modal window will open with related content. Yeah and with the numbers you can slide only one thumbnails.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I couldn't find any that does what I want. and also I would be able to learn as well. If there is any, could you point me towards, so I can inspect it?

Comment: Can't wait to see it in action!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a variable called `margin` that keeps track of the current margin. When arrow navigation is pressed increase or decrease margin by `margin * 4`. If bottom navigation is pressed get the int from a variable that returns which pager was cliceked. If the fourth one is click. just multiply 4 * default margin.

If anyone is interested I can share the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's offset method will return you the position of an element relative to the document. It's not exactly what you need here.

The basic idea behind any slider or carousel is the following:

1. You have a "viewport" element, usually a `div`, which acts as the positioning anchor for everything inside of it. You make it act as an anchor by setting a `position:relative` CSS declaration on it. Also set `overflow:hidden` to hide contents that extend beyond its boundaries. We'll call this `#container`.
2. Within `#container`, you have your list of items, within a `ul` element. The `ul` has `position:absolute` CSS declaration. We'll call this `#content`.
3. Move the `#content` by animating the `left` CSS property.

You have the basic concept down, and using `margin-left` is an adequate solution. But animating the `left` property instead allows you to do some nifty things, like swap in CSS3 transitions and transforms when possible. These will give you hardware-accelerated, buttery-smooth animations.

A terrific plugin to automatically use CSS3 animations where supported is jQuery Animate Enhanced : http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/. It lets you write your code pretty much as you have already, with a few small tweaks, and gain hardware-accelerated graphics where possible.

Comment: thanks a lot for info. I already know how to make a sliders. I have made many sliders using one navigation. But here thing is bit complicated as there are two navigations that I have to look after. But I will definately look for the transitions you have mentioned. I guess jquery.easing has pretty nifty easing effects.